# How to launch my laravel project on another port

Tags: laravel-5

Command line error : `php artisan serve --port=8002` does not work.
It gives me an error like this:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowAbleError]
>   parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`/`' expecting, '`,`' or '`;`'

Comment: The command seems fine. It seems like you have a syntax error somewhere in your application.

Comment: what do you think Mr:Mike where the syntax error can be. I am starting my laravel project through the cmd but it does not start.

Comment: Maybe you can give us more lines from the error message? This does not provide enough information. Please provide the full stacktrace if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```